# Android Application running perfectly in device but crashing in emulator

Tags: android

I have developed an android application. This application runs perfectly in my device but crashes in emulator.
Since in my college we have to present the application in emulator, this error is creating a lot of problem.
Logcat

```
03-30 10:52:52.633: E/AndroidRuntime(257): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.festipedia_logo.main.getActionBar
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at com.example.festipedia_logo.main.onCreate(main.java:51)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-30 10:52:52.653: E/AndroidRuntime(257):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 10:52:52.693: E/dalvikvm(257): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: emulator has old android version that doesn't have action bar. use support library.

Comment: What API level in your code? On the device? On the emulator? @Leonidos is probably right, but there are other possibilities.

Comment: @david.pfx API level of code - 4, device -19, emulator - 7

Comment: @Leonidos I was studying about support library and somewhere in net I came across this statement : `If you are including the v4 support and v7 appcompat libraries in your application, you should specify a minimum SDK version of "7" (and not "4"). The highest support library level you include in your application determines the lowest API version in which it can operate.` In my application I have v 13 and v7 libraries and if I delete v13 library so that the application can support minimum api 7 then It gives an error stating that v13 is required... What should I do??

Answer (score 0):

It is because your emaluator is not supporting action bar. Try either of these

1 -  use action bar sherlock instead of action bar. Google it for its implementation.

2 -  try increasing the android version of emaluator to ICS or more.

I recommend using action bar sherlock

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation, try following it and see if the error is gone.

> The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but
>   they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with
>   Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.
>
> This guide focuses on how to use the support library's action bar, but
>   if your app supports only Android 3.0 or higher, you should use the
>   ActionBar APIs in the framework. Most of the APIs are the same—but
>   reside in a different package namespace—with a few exceptions to
>   method names or signatures that are noted in the sections below.
>
> Caution: Be certain you import the ActionBar class (and related APIs)
>   from the appropriate package:
>
> If supporting API levels lower than 11:
>
> ```
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
> ```
>
> If supporting only API level 11 and higher:
>
> ```
> import android.app.ActionBar
> ```

More At: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

You can also check http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: How can I get support v7 library

Comment: I read this statement : `If you are including the v4 support and v7 appcompat libraries in your application, you should specify a minimum SDK version of "7" (and not "4"). The highest support library level you include in your application determines the lowest API version in which it can operate.`
In my application I have v 13 and v7 libraries and if I delete v13 library so that the application can support minimum api 7 then It gives an error stating that v13 is required... What should I do??

Answer (score 0):

Just tell your emulator to support the same API level as your device and the problem should magically vanish. It's a configuration setting in the emulator.

Comment: Are you still coding for API level 4? Why?

Comment: Should I change it to 7?? My main motive to choose API level 4 was to support all the devices that are available even the lower API's

Comment: If you are trying to support devices at low API levels then you should edit your question accordingly. My answer assumes your device is typical of the level of support you are targeting. Some of the other answers might be more relevant.